# requirejs returns undefined without dependency

Tags: requirejs, undefined, marionette, circular-dependency

On some occasions, `requirejs` returns an undefined object to my module. I've looked at a number of posts and most of the answer are related to circular dependencies. However I could find none (I have checked several times). I apologize by advance for pasting a quantity of code that I've tried to reduced to the minimum :) Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the module `init_app.js` that fails:

```
define([
  'marionette',
], function(
    Marionette
) {
  "use strict";

  var App;
  App = new Marionette.Application();
  App.addRegions({ body: "#main_body" });
  return App;
});
```

Sometimes the `Marionette` module is undefined. Here is the part of my `config.js` that might be relevant:

```
define([], function() {
  'use strict';
  require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths : {
      underscore : 'vendors/underscore/underscore',
      jquery : 'vendors/jquery/dist/jquery',
      backbone : 'vendors/backbone/backbone',
      marionette : 'vendors/marionette/lib/backbone.marionette',
      wreqr : 'vendors/backbone.wreqr/lib/backbone.wreqr',
      eventbinder : 'vendors/backbone.eventbinder/lib/backbone.eventbinder',
      babysitter : 'vendors/backbone.babysitter/lib/backbone.babysitter',
    },
    shim : {
      jquery : {
        exports : 'jQuery'
      },
      underscore : {
        exports : '_'
      },
      backbone : {
        deps : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
        exports : 'Backbone'
      },
      wreqr: {
        deps : ['backbone'],
        exports: 'Backbone.Wreqr'
      },
      eventbinder : {
        deps : ['backbone']
      },
      babysitter : {
        deps: ['backbone']
      },
      marionette : {
        deps: ['backbone', 'wreqr', 'eventbinder', 'babysitter'],
        exports : 'Marionette'
      },
    }
  });
});
```

The `main.js` file is

```
require(['config'], function() {
  require( ['app'], function (App) {
    App.start({});
  });
});
```

where the `app.js` file is

```
define([
  'init_app',
  'router',
], function(
    App,
    Router
  ) {
  "use strict";

  App.on('start', function() {
    new Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
  return App;
});
```

And the router will define a bunch of things that might depend on `init_app.js`. I've been especially carefull that none of them defines the `app.js`, which should be sufficient to guaranty that no circular dependency could cause this bug. Any clue??

Comment: Both `init_app.js` and `app.js`return the same constructor `App`. Can you possibly combine these two modules?

Comment: I don't think so: my router and its dependencies need to access `App.regions` and `App.vent` so I need `App` to be instantiated first. For that they depend on `init_app`. Is it a problem to return several times the same constructor?

Comment: Also, the problem seems to come from the loading of `Marionette` rather than `App`

Comment: I believe returning the same constructor may be your problem. I don't see a problem merging `app.js` and `init_app.js` (we do something similar in our enterprise app). But you could also stick the `start` listener on your `main.js`.

Comment: No, "returning the same constructor" is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should review your `shim` configuration to remove all those shims that you've put in for modules that actually use `define`. For instance, jQuery uses `define` and thus does not need a shim. The same is true of Marionette. I've just installed it with Bower and found this towards the start of the file:

```
 if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['backbone', 'underscore'], function(Backbone, _) {
      return (root.Marionette = root.Mn = factory(root, Backbone, _));
    });
  }
  ...
```

If you see something like this in a module you use, or a flat out call to `define`, then you should not use a shim for it.

I've not checked every single module you use. Please review all of them to make sure you do not use shims where not needed. If you use shims incorrectly, you can get `undefined` values for your modules.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it: I changed the `main.js` to

```
require(['config'], function() {
  require( ['init_app'], function () {
      require( ['app'], function () {
        App.start({});
      });
  });
});
```

and put the `App` in the global scope in `init_app`. This works well but doesn't explain the previous failure.